Router Firmware Reverse Engineering
I wanted to reverse engineer my router's firmware and potentially modify its functionalities.
I know about opensource firmwares like OpenWRT like softwares but I cant use that.
I started with tracking down the firmware my router is using with the exact version. Eventually I found one on the vender's website V2.0.
Searching through the internet, I came across this article- https://www.zerodayinitiative.com/blog/2020/2/6/mindshare-dealing-with-encrypted-router-firmware.
But the Firmware is not encrypted, its just compressed with LZMA into the .bin file.
The Binwalk output:-
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10292         0x2834          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2768760 bytes

Its later version V5.0 here has some more information. Inspecting it with binwalk shows:
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
28            0x1C            uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x55717000, created: 2020-04-30 14:40:49, image size: 1005874 bytes, Data Address: 0x80000000, Entry Point: 0x800001BC, data CRC: 0x55717040, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "eCosAP"
60            0x3C            eCos RTOS string reference: "eCosAP"
92            0x5C            LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 3118960 bytes

An older version V1.0 which I got from searching on internet show some other thing:
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             TRX firmware header, little endian, image size: 942080 bytes, CRC32: 0xA239E569, flags: 0x0, version: 1, header size: 28 bytes, loader offset: 0x1C, linux kernel offset: 0x0, rootfs offset: 0x0
28            0x1C            LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 2529180 bytes

I decompressed the LZMA data of the original V2.0 and It had some files inside it but no such filesystem. I am stuck here.
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             eCos kernel exception handler, architecture: MIPS, exception vector table base address: 0x80000200
128           0x80            eCos kernel exception handler, architecture: MIPS, exception vector table base address: 0x80000200
134911        0x20EFF         GPG key trust database version 93
198940        0x3091C         SHA256 hash constants, big endian
1463384       0x165458        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos Release: %d.%d.%d"
1489752       0x16BB58        Unix path: /dev/net/dhcpc
1490680       0x16BEF8        Unix path: /dev/net/dhcpd
1492256       0x16C520        Unix path: /dev/net/ipl
1502392       0x16ECB8        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos_name"
1502404       0x16ECC4        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos"
1511184       0x170F10        XML document, version: "1.0"
1511800       0x171178        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS"
1514232       0x171AF8        XML document, version: "1.0"
1515000       0x171DF8        XML document, version: "1.0"
1521128       0x1735E8        XML document, version: "1.0"
1523396       0x173EC4        Unix path: /dev/net/ppp/ppp%d
1526592       0x174B40        Unix path: /dev/net/pppoe/%s
1533779       0x176753        HTML document footer
1534744       0x176B18        HTML document footer
1534852       0x176B84        HTML document header
1535624       0x176E88        HTML document header
1535731       0x176EF3        HTML document footer
1535756       0x176F0C        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos_pw=%s:language=%s; path=/"
1535856       0x176F70        HTML document header
1536016       0x177010        HTML document footer
1538300       0x1778FC        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos_cgi/cgi_devManage.c"
1541756       0x17867C        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos_pw="
1558984       0x17C9C8        Base64 standard index table
1565160       0x17E1E8        SHA256 hash constants, big endian
1576440       0x180DF8        Base64 standard index table
1577228       0x18110C        CRC32 polynomial table, big endian
1582401       0x182541        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-work/../ecos-3.0/packages/devs/eth/rltk/819x/switch/v3_0/src/swNic_poll.c"
1582414       0x18254E        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-3.0/packages/devs/eth/rltk/819x/switch/v3_0/src/swNic_poll.c"
1584313       0x182CB9        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-work/../ecos-3.0/packages/devs/eth/rltk/819x/switch/v3_0/src/swTable.c"
1584326       0x182CC6        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-3.0/packages/devs/eth/rltk/819x/switch/v3_0/src/swTable.c"
1585297       0x183091        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-work/../ecos-3.0/packages/devs/eth/rltk/819x/switch/v3_0/src/vlanTable.c"
1585310       0x18309E        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-3.0/packages/devs/eth/rltk/819x/switch/v3_0/src/vlanTable.c"
1585445       0x183125        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-work/../ecos-3.0/packages/devs/eth/rltk/819x/switch/v3_0/src/rtl865x_igmpsnooping_new.c"
1585458       0x183132        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-3.0/packages/devs/eth/rltk/819x/switch/v3_0/src/rtl865x_igmpsnooping_new.c"
1630142       0x18DFBE        XML document, version: "1.0"
1630320       0x18E070        HTML document header
1630385       0x18E0B1        HTML document footer
1630556       0x18E15C        Base64 standard index table
1630834       0x18E272        HTML document header
1630959       0x18E2EF        HTML document footer
1631240       0x18E408        HTML document header
1631380       0x18E494        HTML document footer
1631392       0x18E4A0        HTML document header
1631422       0x18E4BE        HTML document footer
1631876       0x18E684        XML document, version: "1.0"
1638240       0x18FF60        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_node"
1646208       0x191E80        Unix path: /var/log/alias.log
1690660       0x19CC24        XML document, version: "1.0"
1701188       0x19F544        XML document, version: "1.0"
1704232       0x1A0128        XML document, version: "1.0"
1705204       0x1A04F4        XML document, version: "1.0"
1711196       0x1A1C5C        XML document, version: "1.0"
2228680       0x2201C8        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2228732       0x2201FC        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2228800       0x220240        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2229120       0x220380        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2234836       0x2219D4        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2234888       0x221A08        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2234920       0x221A28        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2235072       0x221AC0        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2235104       0x221AE0        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2235444       0x221C34        Zlib compressed data, default compression
2266010       0x22939A        Base64 standard index table
2273032       0x22AF08        Copyright string: "Copyright 2013 Scott Jehl"
2326473       0x237FC9        HTML document header
2326479       0x237FCF        HTML document footer
2327221       0x2382B5        HTML document header
2327227       0x2382BB        HTML document footer
2327836       0x23851C        Copyright string: "Copyright 2014 ET.W"
2331409       0x239311        Copyright string: "Copyright 2013 reasy Foundation and other contributors"
2334491       0x239F1B        Copyright string: "Copyright 2013 reasy Foundation and other contributors"
2338597       0x23AF25        Copyright string: "Copyright 2013 reasy Foundation and other contributors"
2345422       0x23C9CE        Copyright string: "Copyright 2013 reasy Foundation and other contributors"
2346228       0x23CCF4        Copyright string: "C
2532356       0x26A404        GIF image data, vers
2533764       0x26A984        PNG image, 160 x 160
2533805       0x26A9AD        Zlib compressed data
2535448       0x26B018        PNG image, 80 x 12, 
2536448       0x26B400        PNG image, 24 x 10, 
2536824       0x26B578        PNG image, 32 x 20, 
2537372       0x26B79C        PNG image, 20 x 20, 
2537580       0x26B86C        PNG image, 133 x 30,
2540400       0x26C370        PNG image, 116 x 26,
2548511       0x26E31F        HTML document header
2551874       0x26F042        HTML document footer
2551899       0x26F05B        HTML document header
2552916       0x26F454        HTML document footer
2560523       0x27120B        HTML document header
2568797       0x27325D        HTML document footer
2579095       0x275A97        HTML document header
2585129       0x277229        HTML document footer
2609636       0x27D1E4        AES S-Box

I can access all the files inside with dd (and they work and open as intended the PNGs, HTML files, etc). But I want to inject some files in it.
Also suggest a way to emulate the firmware and check for its integrity (Its a router firmware, so no GUI, the way to check it will be accessing the web management portal).

Router model? Link to firmware? The decompressed stuff (binwalk output?) at least partially looks like what you would expect from a router firmware. There also seems to be more compressed data.

@secfren sorry, my bad. I have now added the firmware link. You can test it.

You could try to extract all the files with binwalk -eM and insert the modified files in the hierarchy, finally rebuild the archive with lzma. You may need to find the CRC of the archive and change it.

@perror the thing is binwalk -eM just output a number of zlib data and nothing else. i tried to extract thst too but its again a number of further zlib data
